# Mysql dataadapter InsertCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have following code

```
MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySQLCon"]);
MySqlDataAdapter dAdap = new MySqlDataAdapter();
dAdap.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("insert into PMduedates(eCId,ECClass,ddate,PMType) values(eCId,ECClass,ddate,PMType)", myCon);
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("eCId", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "eqpID");
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ECClass", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "class");
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ddate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "MaintType");
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("PMType", MySqlDbType.Date, 10, "Duedate");
myCon.Open();
dAdap.Update(dtDue);
myCon.Close();
```

In the above code dtDue is a datatable and eqpID,class,MaintType and Duedate are datacolumns. when i am executing code it does n't gives any error but data is not updating in table PMduedates.

Comment: Why don't you change the Insert.Parameters.Add method to InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue and just pass the Param, Value and let the database server handle the type. also don't you need to do ExecuteNonQuery command on DataAdapter..?

Answer (score 1):

Why should the `DataAdapter` insert the records in the `DataTable`? Nobody told it to do so. It will insert rows only if they are in [`RowState.Added`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx), you can force it in this way:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtDue.Rows)
    row.SetAdded();
```

but since you are providing the insert-command and the parameters manually anyway, i would execute the query also manually:

```
using(var myCon = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySQLCon"]))
using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into PMduedates(eCId,ECClass,ddate,PMType) values(eCId,ECClass,ddate,PMType)", myCon))
{
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("eCId", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "eqpID");
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ECClass", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "class");
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ddate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "MaintType");
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("PMType", MySqlDbType.Date, 10, "Duedate");
    myCon.Open();
    int countInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} // using closes the connection implicitely
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have named your parameters and columns the same change the parameter names, for example try this:

```
MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySQLCon"]);
MySqlDataAdapter dAdap = new MySqlDataAdapter();
dAdap.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("insert into PMduedates(eqpID,class,Duedate,MaintType) values(@eCId,@ECClass,@ddate,@PMType)", myCon);
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@eCId", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "eqpID");
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ECClass", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "class");
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ddate", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "MaintType");
dAdap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@PMType", MySqlDbType.Date, 10, "Duedate");
myCon.Open();
dAdap.Update(dtDue);
myCon.Close();
```